# Breaking Long Equation inside Algorithm box

Tags: equations, formatting, algorithms

I tried to break the following equation to multiple lines as it's stretching outside of Algorithm box in my LaTex document,

```
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

Thread Data$(\zeta, \epsilon)$\\
\Input{Packets}
\Output{Dataset}

\For{k iterations} {

\For {d steps} {

$$
\nabla_{\theta} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left[ \log{D_{\theta}(x^{(i)})} +\log({1 - D_{\theta}(G_{\phi}(z^{(i)}))}) \right]
$$\\

}

}
\caption{Algorithm 1.}
\end{algorithm}
```

Those are the packages I used,

```
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
```

**Output**,

[image]

**Edit**:

This is a two-column document.

Comment: Which document class do you employ?  Is the document in twol-column mode?

Comment: @Mico. Yeah two-column mode. Sorry I forgot to add that. I edited it.

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: @Mico. It's IEEEtran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions: use a Times compatible math font instead of the default (which is Computer Modern Math); don't use `$$ ... $$`, instead, use `$\displaystyle ... $`; write `\nabla_{\!\theta}`, `D_{\!\theta}`, and `G_{\!\phi}`, i.e., reduce the space between the main symbols and their respective subscripts; and don't use `\left` and `\right` -- instead, use `\bigl` and `\bigr`.

Aside: If you use inline math instead of display math and refrain from using `\left` and `\right`, LaTeX will likely find a suitable line break on its own, should the equation still be too long to fit. To verify this, add the document class option `12pt` to the following code and recompile.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
%% (pared the preamble down to the bare minimum)
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxmath}   % <-- use a Times-type math font
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

Thread Data$(\zeta, \epsilon)$\\
\Input{Packets}
\Output{Dataset}

\For{$k$ iterations} {

\For {$d$ steps} {
$\displaystyle
\nabla_{\!\theta}\, \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} 
   \bigl[ \log D_{\!\theta}(x^{(i)}) +
   \log\bigl({1 - D_{\!\theta}(G_{\!\phi}(z^{(i)}))}\bigr) \bigr]
$\\
}
}
\caption{Algorithm 1.}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. Could you please tell me what are the packages that you used?

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxmath}   % <-- use a Times-type math font

Comment: Thank you. How to add the document class option 12pt? I am new to LaTex, so pardon me.

Comment: @Abraheem - `mathtools` is a superset of `amsmath`, and `amsymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically; hence, there's no need to load `amsmath` and `amsfonts` separately. The IEEEtran document class loads a Times Roman *text* font, but leaves the math font unchanged. The `newtxmath` package provides a Times Roman math font.

Comment: @Abraheem - `\usepackage[12pt]{IEEEtran}`.

Comment: I added mathtools instead, but I have errors now as the following is no more working? 

\begin{multline}

\end{multline}

Comment: Thank you. So, \usepackage[12pt]{IEEEtran} will set the whole font of document to 12 pt?

Comment: @Abraheem - the option `12pt` sets the document's *main* font size to 12pt. Footnotes will still be 20% smaller than regular text.

Comment: Thank you. When I added  \usepackage[12pt]{IEEEtran}, I got LaTex Error: File `IEEEtran.sty` not found

Comment: @Abraheem - Sadly, my mind-reading skills are absolute rubbish. Please provide more, usable information about *how* you try to use the `multline` environment.

Comment: @Abraheem -- Sorry, that was a **typo**. It should have been `\documentclass[12pt]{IEEEtran}`, not `\usepackage[12pt]{IEEEtran}`.

Comment: Thank you. That is okay. I just tried to add some equations as follows between multiline, but it's not working after I deleted "amsmath, amsymb, amsfonts". Do you mean I should add mathtools  instead of amsmath and keep amsymb, amsfonts in order for multline to work?

Comment: I added the following instead of multiline, but it gave me errors, 

$\displaystyle
   x\sim \left( 1-\!\varepsilon \right) \mathscr{N}\left(\!\mu _0,\!\Sigma _W \right) +\sum\limits_{h=1}^q{\!\epsilon _h\mathscr{N}\left( \!\mu _h,\!\Sigma _W \right)}
$\\

Comment: @Abraheem - You asked, "Do you mean I should add `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`?" *Yes*.

Comment: The packages are fine now. Thanks. The display style above in my previous comment does not work, I am not sure where I got mistaken?

Comment: @Abraheem - Did you miss the "refrain from using `\left` and `\right`" condition in my answer? For sure, I wrote this for a very good reason. You ignore this at your own peril.

Comment: Thank you. I understand you said replace them with \bigl and \bigr, but will this adapt to all sizes of equations? I mean does it mean that the brackets or braces will be large or something?

Comment: @Abraheem - Please ask a **new question** regarding the meaning of `\bigl` and `\bigr`.

Comment: I added a new post on multiline and displaymath you told me about : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588971/differences-between-displaymath-and-multiline