# Differences between displaymath and multiline

Tags: equations, formatting

I added the following equation based on IEEE two-column document,

```
$\displaystyle x\sim \left( 1-\!\varepsilon \right) \mathscr{N}\left(\!\mu _0,\!\Sigma _W \right) +\sum\limits_{h=1}^q{\!\epsilon _h\mathscr{N}\left( \!\mu _h,\!\Sigma _W \right)} $\\
```

However, this does not automatically number my equations in the document. On the contrary, multiline did not but it only numbers the whole block of the equations and not one by one separated by "\". I added "\" at the end to separate equations and number the one on the nextline, but still got the same number. How to write one block for 3 equations with one number for each?

```
\begin{multline}
x\sim \left(1-\varepsilon \right) \mathcal{N} \left(\mu _0,\Sigma _W \right) +\sum\limits_{h=1}^q{\epsilon _h\mathcal{N} \left( \mu _h,\Sigma _W \right)}\\
\end{multline}
```

**Edit**:

I used \begin{align} instead of multiline and it's aligning equations properly now and number multiple equations automatically. I add `\\` at the end of each equation to separate it and to number it with different number.

Comment: Off-topic: Not a single `\left` or `\right` directive in your code is doing anything useful. Using `\left` and `\right` indiscriminately is very poor practice. For sure, this practice is *not innocuous*, as it messes with the horizontal spacing and creates dreadful code clutter. Why are you creating so much code clutter?

Comment: That is right. I did not notice that before. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Multiline does not number equations automatically even though I added "\\" at the end of each equation but align does that, could you please explain why that is the case?

Comment: Why do you think that `$\displaystyle ... $` would place the formula on a line by itself and be given an equation number? A separate comment: The `multline` environment should *not* be used if you need to display separate equations, each with their own equation number; for such cases, use either `gather` or `align` environments. Please study section 3, "Displayed equations", of the [user guide](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) of the `amsmath` package for some basic information about the properties of the `align`, `gather`, and `multline` environments.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. Thanks for the guide. One final question about $\displaystyle ... $, it's used only inside algorithm and can not be used to assign numbers?

Comment: $...$ is for inline math which, by definition, cannot be assigned an equation number. Please study any basic TeX or LaTeX guide to understand the very fundamental and important difference between inline and display math mode in TeX and LaTeX documents.